# Javascript: Generating a URL from two text inputs and a radio button input

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form with two integer-only text boxes, one group of radio buttons, and a submit button. I would like it to take the values of these three inputs, and use them to generate a URL with three variables, like so:

```
http://domain.com/file.php?var1=&var2=&var3=
```

EDIT: To clarify, the output is on the page, not in the URL. I have created a php image that displays different things, based on the URL variables, and this image should be able to be used on other sites as the user sees fit.

EDIT2: My basic HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="var1" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="var2" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="var3" value="1" />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="var3" value="2" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="URLGenerate" value="Generate" />
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean a GET request?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think so. I chose JS because you don't have to refresh the page for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is how you can solve this problem:

*1. Create the HTML*

You need to assign a `id` to every text box (text boxes are defined as `<input type="text"/>` in html. Then you need the radio buttons which are defined as `<input type="radio"/>`. Make sure that all radio buttons have the same `name` attribute. Here is a [short intro](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm).

*2. Get the values with Javascript*

You can access every element by its id.

*3. Change the current URL*

After making the URL, you can change it by assigning to `window.location` in Javascript.

I guess if someone wants to make it simpler, they have to type the code for you! ;)

**Update**

Using the code that you added to the question, I created a javascript program that solves the problem:

```
//assign the button event handler
document.getElementById( 'URLGenerate' ).addEventListener( 'click', onGenerate );

//given the name of a radio button group, it returns the value of the selected radio button or null if none of them are selected
function getRadioButtonValue ( name ) {
  var allRadios = document.getElementsByName( name );
  for ( var i = 0; i < allRadios.length; i++ ) {
    if ( allRadios[i].checked ) {
      return allRadios[ i ].value;
    }
  }
  return null;//or any other value when nothing is selected
}

function onGenerate() {
  //the base url
  var url = 'http://domain.com/file.php';
  //an array of all the parameters
  var params = [];
  //get the value from the edit box with id=var1
  params.push( 'var1=' + document.getElementById( 'var1' ).value );
  //get the value from the edit box with id=var2
  params.push( 'var2=' + document.getElementById( 'var2' ).value );

  //get the value of the radio box
  params.push( 'var3=' + getRadioButtonValue( 'var3' ) );

  //join all the parameters together and add to the url
  url += '?' + params.join( '&' );
  alert( url );
}
```

Here is a [JSBin to try it live](http://jsbin.com/itovat/3/) and you can see the HTML/JS here: http://jsbin.com/itovat/3/edit

Comment: 1: The HTML is already made. That was the easy part. It is 2 that I have a problem with, because...Well, I don't know my JS very well. 3 is something I don't need to do, though

Comment: I can help you much better if I see your HTML code. Please put the part of code that you want help with.

Comment: Beauty! One final thing. Rather than an alert, how can I display it on the page itself, where the HTML is: URL: <span id="URL" >&nbsp;</span>

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out on my own. Thanks for your help, mate!